# Pop up showing behind form and freezes program

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

The following pertains to vb.net 2010

Hi, I have a program that is relatively simple. It's a form with some text and a webbrowser control on it. The webbrowser connects to my companies sharepoint site. Whenever you click on a document (like a hosted word or excel file), you get a popup asking for you to enter your username and password for sharepoint. However, the popup appears behind the main form and freezes the form so you cannot do anything. I do not have the main form set to always be on top.

Any thoughts on how I could hide the form when the link is clicked and have it show again after the user enters the credentials?

Other info: I have 2 monitors. when I move the form off the screen and click the link, I can enter my credentials because the pop up occurs in the middle of the main screen and everything goes back to working smoothly. There's not much code in the program to post, just drag and dropping controls onto the form.

Comment: Relevant code ahead & behind will help us out.

Comment: I dont really have any code. I just set the default page of the sharepoint page and I have script supression on because of a bunch of javascript error popups.  Its not that another form opens what happens is when you click the Word document you must enter your username and password in a standard javascript popup box  this box is not part of my code but a security of sharepoint on the document itself  the same happens if you were to go through IE. But in my prpgeam the popup occurs behind the main form which is not set to Top Most

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ancestors, your form and another Ancestor,
Your form is set to top-most and the next Ancestor is the parent of the mesbox.

```
MessageBox.Show(New System.Windows.Forms.Form, "Ill be on the back cause im a new back form")
```

Comment: Hello Avishay, there is only one form and inside it is the web browser control. The pop up is not a form of my program but rather credentials pop up for security used on the actual sharepoint site. SO if you want to open a word file hosted on the page you must enter your credentials. Is there a way to hide the program when a link is clicked inside the web browser with a specific file extension?